# How can I compile my overleaf project from scratch

Tags: bibtex, overleaf, compilation-error

I have problem with my overleaf project. The compile error is the following:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016/Debian)
Capacity: max_strings=100000, hash_size=100000, hash_prime=85009
The top-level auxiliary file: nonsmoothCFLP.aux
The style file: model5-names.bst
Database file #1: literature.bib
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 645 of file literature.bib
 : author = "Mikael R\"
 :                     {o}nnqvist and Suda Tragantalerngsak and John Holt"
```

I removed the bibtex entry corresponding to the error. Therefore, the line 645 does not exist. However, the error keeps. I renamed the database file "literature.bib" by "references.bib" and I wrote \bibliography{references} command in the main tex file in such a way that compiler take the new bibtex file. However, the error is the same. I suppose that I need to remove temporal files of compilation, and thus, I want to know how can I compile from scratch.

Comment: If you really get still this error no temporary file is involved. This is an error in the bib-file. Perhaps you had more than one of this faulty umlauts.

Answer (score 1):

When you get an error and click on the red Compile Error box at the top right of the Preview pane should should see a drop down menu with a Recompile From Scratch option.

If the option doesn't appear, you may need to make some changes to the document to force a recompile. For bibliography related things commenting out your bibliography command might work; for other things simply introducing a deliberate error might also work.

[image: screen shot from Overleaf]

Comment: I don't have this option.

Comment: @AlejandroEstradaMoreno Try making a deliberate error in the file. It might make it appear.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I comment the following line and the problem was solved:

%% APA style
\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

When I make another deliberated error in the file does not work.

Comment: @AlejandroEstradaMoreno Good to know. I'll add a bit to the answer. It's annoying that the option isn't available always.

Comment: I usually simulate a warning with `\PackageWarning{foo}{bar}` or `\ref{foo}`. On Overleaf v2 (similar interface to ShareLaTeX) this option will always be present: Click on the "logs and other files" icon next to "Recompile", scroll to bottom, click on the Trash icon to clear all generated files.

Comment: The approach to simulate the warning is ok, but at this time the `Clean Cache` does not work!